# Authorization Header and Base64 Encoding in VimeoAPI

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am new to the world of APIs and Auth, and would certainly appreciate any help. I am attempting to authorize and receive a token through the Vimeo API (OAuth2). My question is how to properly set the value of the Authorization Header. (Table below from: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication)

| Header | Set value to |
| --- | --- |
| Authorization | `basic base64_encode(x:y)`, where x is the client identifier and y is the client secret |

In this table is `base64_encode` plain text that I need to write, or does this denote a function I need to use in my language that converts `x:y` into Base64? M Language, in my case.

Also, are my clientID and clientSecret ready to put into the header "as-is" or do they themselves need to be converted into Base64 before being used as auth for the token endpoint?

The gist of my confusion is how exactly I should write the authorization header, because I keep getting the error `"[invalid_client] A valid client ID must be provided along with any request made to Vimeo's API" when trying to POST to the token endpoint.`

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4):

The idea that you should use some sort of function to encode your clientID and secret is correct.

If you are using javascript the code might looks something like this

```js
const clientId = 'client_id';
const clientSecret = 'client_secret';

// btoa() is a javascript built-in that base64 encodes a string
const authorizationValue = 'Basic ' + btoa( clientId + ':' + clientSecret );
```

You can read more about btoa() on Mozilla's documentation website.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa